# Find sum of occurrence of elements in sliced-list mapped to index of element

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
my_list=['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Kevin', 'Kevin', 'Bryan']
```

I want to create a new list which is used to count the sum of all occurrences of a unique value in my_list as my_list is iterated over. The iteration should start with the first item in my_list and go over all items in my_list.

For example, I want a list that looks like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: If the list were `['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Kevin', 'Kevin', 'Bryan', 'John']`, would the result be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5]`? In other words, do you want the sequential occurrences up to that point or the sum of all occurrences up to that point?

Comment: I ask because the [currently accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40754341/1399279) does the latter, where the words in your text indicates you want the former.

Comment: @SethMMorton currently that isn't specified in the question so I'd recommend you un-delete your answer because it is a good one - just add a note about what assumptions it makes.

Comment: @SethMMorton within the context of my usage this example list you gave would not occur. However, if it did occur then the correct way to handle it would be to return the sum of all occurrences up to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`list.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to find the occurence of word on the sliced list along with *list comprehension*:

```
>>> my_list= ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Kevin', 'Kevin', 'Bryan']
>>> [my_list[:i].count(name) for i, name in enumerate(my_list, 1)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Here, `my_list[:i].count(name)` will give the count of occurrence of `name` in `my_list` from `0`th to `i`th index (excluding the value at `i`th index). To know about [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), refer the [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). I am passing `start = 1` with enumerate which means value of `i` will start from `1`.

Example related to slicing and count:

```
>>> my_list[:6]      # Values upto `5`th index
['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Joe', 'Joe']  
>>> my_list[:6].count('John')   # occurence of `John` in the list
4
```

---

**Edit:**  The equivalent conversion of this *list comprehension* expression to the `for` loop will be:

```
my_count = []                #    v  Means index `i` starting from `1`
for i, name in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    word_count = my_list[:i].count(name)
    my_count.append(word_count)
```

Here `my_count` will hold the same value which was retuned by the list comprehension.

Comment: I'm not a fan of your explanation of `my_list[:i].count(name)` does, it doesn't count up to including `i`, it just makes `i` one index further then the current iteration by specifying a `start=1` to `enumerate`.  This is fine if someone already understands this but it isn't readily apparent why it is working.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: After giving the second look at it. I too realize that you are right. Updated the answer. I think now it show be clear. Let me know your thought :)

Comment: Use a different value for `i` in your example.  You have `i=3`, which happens to equal the length of the list and number returned for count.  It can get confusing.  Try `i=4` for a list of length 5.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri i don't have a strong knowledge of list comprehension so your usage of `my_list[:i].count(name) for i` is not immediately clear to me. Is `i` sequentially increasing as we iterate over the list?

Comment: @firetheRookie: Check edit, I believe it should be clear now

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to construct a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) while simultaneously generating the counts at each iteration of the list:

```
from collections import Counter

def stepped_counter(sequence):
    seen = Counter()
    for item in sequence:
        seen[item]+=1 #add in the item
        yield seen[item] #generate the current count of this item

>>> my_list= ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Kevin', 'Kevin', 'Bryan']
>>> list(stepped_counter(my_list))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This is a clean way to do it :)  I'd include the output for completeness.